# PC inaccessible after login

Tags: kubuntu, connection

I can't figure out what's going on on my machine

Following my password identification I get the usual desktop environment, but I cannot perform any action. No program responds. I'm unable to call a tty (Ctrl+Alt+F2 to F6).
Is the computer  being monopolized by a task? There is continuous disk access.
It is only after a few long minutes that I'm able to use the PC. I managed to get a tty and a curious message appeared about a kioslave5 process being killed, and it seems to coincide with the correct use of the PC.
I confirm this assertion.
It's when the process is killed by the system as above or when it has finished its job that I can finally find my desktop.
It also looks like it activates a thumbnail.so file.

Specs:

OS : Kubuntu 22.04
  Version of KDE Plasma : 5.24.7
  Version of KDE Frameworks : 5.92.0
  Version of Qt : 5.15.3
  Version of kernel : 5.19.0-41-generic (64-bit)
  Graphics platform : X11
  Processors : 4 × AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 955 processor
  Memory : 3.3 GB RAM
  Graphics processor : AMD RS880

Comment: Could be [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kio/+bug/1971477).

Comment: I have the similar problem with kioslave5, it eats 12% of 8-kernels processor.